# Jquery img.onload doesn't run in the for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, onload

I am trying to do a dynamic image gallery, where all the images named as index (eg. "150.jpg") As they are indexed the images in order would look like this: 1.jpg, 50.jpg, 200.jpg etc...
Here I created a for loop which will check if image with given name exists and if it is then stop the loop.
Here is my code:

```
var x = 1;
for (w=0;w==0;x++){ 
var newurl = imgfolder + x + ".jpg";
var img = new Image();
img.src = newurl;
img.onload = function() {alert("Yeah:Image exists"); w=1;} ;
}
```

The problem is that without the for loop it work fine, but when it's inside the loop then the img.onload doesn't run. Any help will be appreciated as this gives me a headache for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the `onload =` before the `src =`

This is because the image can be taken from cache and thus be instantly loaded.
When you define `onload =` in the next line, it may already be too late.

[edit:]

Besides that there is another problem:

Imagine the flow:

- `for (w=0;w==0;x++){`

  - `w=0`
  - `w==0` is true, so go on
- `var newurl = imgfolder + x + ".jpg";`
- `var img = new Image();`
- `img.src = newurl;`
- `img.onload = function() {alert("Yeah:Image exists"); w=1;} ;`
- `for (w=0;w==0;x++){`

  - `w==0` is still true, so go on
- `var newurl = imgfolder + x + ".jpg";`
- ...

There is one problem with that: JavaScript is single threaded! That means nothing can run asynchronously. And because your code never stops there is no chance for the `alert("Yeah:Image exists"); w=1;` to get executed. But executing `w=1` is your only chance to get out of the loop.

Comment: My bad, thit is how it was originally, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition prevents it from iterating. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

```
for (x=0; x<10; x++){ 
    var newurl = imgfolder + x + ".jpg";
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {alert("Yeah:Image exists"); w=1;} ;
    img.src = newurl;
}
```

I also changed the order of the onload assignment as @Matmarbon suggested.

Comment: The problem is still the same, even if I change the condition so it will stop aftert lets say after 10 iteration (which is wrong because I want the loop to break only if the img URL exists) it still doesn't run the onload event. Again without the loop it works. This is my code now:`for (w=0;w<10;x++){
      var newurl = imgfolder + x + ".jpg";
      var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function() {  alert(newurl); };
         img.src = newurl;
      w++;
      }    `
I really want to understand why. It just skips `img.onload`.